# ..., die Gegenstand ist?

Tags: grammatical-case, noun, article, grammaticality

I am a beginner in German and this is my first post. 
I encounter the following sentence in a German article:

> In vielen Fällen folgt diese Eigenschaft aus Satz 1, die Gegenstand dieses Kapitels ist.

I can not understand the use of "**die**" in front of "**Gegenstand**"(subject, topic, theme, etc.). 
According to the [online dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gegenstand),  "Gegenstand" is masculine, and the only two cases of a leading "die" are: nominative plural and accusative plural, where the word should be "**Gegenstände**".

Is "die Gegenstand" grammatically correct ?

Comment: For a good explanation we need this part of the sentence you omitted, as "die" refers to this part.

Comment: For reference: Der Sachverhalt , der Gegenstand ist ... ----- Die Frage, die Gegenstand ist ...  ----- Das Problem, das Gegenstand ist....

Comment: @IQV The subject of the main sentence is "diese Eigenschaft". See my comment below Faenrig's answer.

Comment: Since comments could be deleted in the future, I added it to your question.

Comment: @booksee: as it stands now this example sentence still does not make much sense to me. Please [edit] it for completion.

Comment: *In many cases this property ..., **which** is the subject of this chapter.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sentence is grammatically correct as long as there is a feminine object in the main sentence. The **die** so relates to this feminine word then.

> In vielen Fällen ... , die Gegenstand dieses Kapitels ist.

As an example

> In vielen Fällen tritt *eine Messunsicherheit* auf, die Gegenstand dieses Kapitels ist.

In english you would rather say:

> [...], *which is* the topic of this chapter.

So it is not an article but rather a relative pronoun that is related to a previous subject and changes on its genus.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Edited.

Comment: *Eine Messunsicherheit* is the subject to *auftreten*, not an accusative object.

Comment: @Faenrig You're right. There is a feminine subject "diese Eigenschaft" in the main sentence, so "die...ist" corresponds to "Eigenschaft".

Answer (score 3):

Die isn't the article of "Gegenstand" here. It is a relative pronoun referring back to "Fälle(n)". In the subordinate clause after the comma "die" thus acts as the subject. You could translate it with "that"

Comment: It doesn't refer to _Fälle_, but to another feminie noun hidden behind the  ellipsis.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I agree with you. I think "die...ist" should refer to a singular noun while "vielen Fälle(n)" is obviously plural.

Answer (score 2):

*Der*, *die* and *das* have different functions in the German language. While they *can* be articles to a noun, they can also be demonstrative pronouns or relative pronouns. In your sentence, it is the latter. The sentence would translate as:

> In many cases ..., which is the subject of this chapter.